# TinyMCE init fails after ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4.1.10 to enable inline editing on several divs on a page. Everything works fine on initial page load, but if I tear down the editors and rebind the textareas in an ajax call TinyMCE won't hook back up to them. The binding is done with Knockout.

Here is the function that initially loads the data, and also gets called when a refresh occurs.

```
    this.loadLetterFields = function () {
        var editors = $("div.editable");
        for (var i = editors.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            var ed_id = editors[i].id;
            tinymce.execCommand("mceRemoveEditor", false, ed_id);
        }

        $.getJSON(_this.fieldURL + "/" + _this.letterId() + "/" + _this.clientId() + "/" + _this.caseId(), function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                // Reload fields
            }
        });

        tinymce.init({
            selector: "div.editable",
            inline: true,
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            toolbar: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent",
            forced_root_block: false
        });
    };
```

I've pieced what I have together from several SO posts, but this seems to be a recurring issue. Are there any solutions? Is this a known bug?

**Update:**
I just noticed that it doesn't seem to be *all* of the divs, but there is not difference in the divs that are working and the ones that aren't. They are all generated by the same ko if binding.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar issue. My solution was to call `tinyMCE.remove();` before calling the reload. Then `tinyMCE.init();` would work as expected.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks

Comment: You can just call `tinyMCE.remove();` and immediately after call `tinyMCE.init();`, those lines can just be above eachother; even *after* a reload.